# Any abelian group embeds into a Chow group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, complex-geometry

Let $G$ be an abelian group. Must there exist a perfect field $k$, a smooth projective geometrically connected $k$-scheme $X$ and an integer $i\geq 0$ such that $G$ embeds into the integral Chow group $CH^i(X)$?

Comment: Any motivation for this question?

Comment: To better understand the Chow groups.

Comment: How it helps to understand Chow group?

Comment: By describing its subgroups.